# How to make/generate a graph image depending on values in a database?

Tags: php, database, graphics, graph

How could I make an image graph from values in a database? The idea came from "Steam", which uses a graph to show how many users are online. How could I do the same thing? It seems like the graph is one whole image; not made up of parts. Here's an image of the graph from Steam:
[alt text http://d-load.org/public/steam-graph.PNG](http://d-load.org/public/steam-graph.PNG)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this GD module from PHP. http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php

Answer (score 5):

You want to use JPGraph, it is a very power PHP graphing library.
http://www.aditus.nu/jpgraph/

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way is using the [Google Chart API](http://code.google.com/apis/chart/image_charts.html). You can generate a graph by simply creating a url with your values ([basic example](http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?chs=200x105&cht=ls&chco=0077CC&chd=t:3,5,8,10,15,20,27,25,60,31,25,39,25,31,26,28,80,28,27,31,27,29,26,35,70,25))

Answer (score 2):

You will mainly need to keep a track of how many users were connected at each period of time. Drawing the graph is easy, they are some really neat library to help you with it. ;)

Answer (score 2):

+1 for Svisstack's link. Here's another one (less supported, less documented, but more features): http://www.php.net/imagick

Comment: I know about ImageMagick being used for scaling images and doing other image processing operations.  But how does it help with creating an image from raw data?

Comment: Yes, it can be used to create images from scratch and draw on them.

Answer (score 1):

if you are the javascript lover use this, http://raphaeljs.com/

they keep updating and many advance function.

Comment: Great find: this turned out to be the best solution for doing some very custom stuff.  A bit low level and thus more challenging to work with, still worked like a charm for my needs.  The demo source code makes it fairly easy to just jump in.

Answer (score 0):

I use FLOT with Jquery -> http://code.google.com/p/flot/

I find it easier to work with CSS than GD library to get the layout I want.

Answer (score 0):

There are many javascript-tools. For example, you can choose [jQuery's plugin - jqplot](http://www.jqplot.com/) or [Dojo charting](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/charting.html) etc...
With those, you can generate very good-looking charts/graphs.